# CORS enable in Owin

Tags: cors, owin, nancy

I have been trying to make CORS enable in an ASP.Net application running on OWIN.

Here's my code:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        //Enable CORS
        //Use JWTOwinAuth middleware
        //Use Nancy framework
        app     
            .UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll)                  
            .Use(typeof(JwtOwinAuth))
            .UseNancy();

    }
}
```

The CorsOptions.AllowAll seems not to work and I get "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource".

I already tried all suggestions from the net but still the solutions are not working.

Comment: for web-api you want to use cors?

Comment: Yes, I am hosting this web service in appharbor and a "front-end"web app is connecting to this "web service". However, No Access-Control-Allow-Origin is being encountered by the frontend. My first implementation was using WebApp.Start<Startup>(url), which is a console application, and this is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

there are two things you need to do

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
       var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
        config.EnableCors(cors);
       ........
```

and (this one you have done)

```
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
         app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
    ........
```

Comment: I am not sure if I am making a correct implementation but I tried this suggestion. Added a WebApiConfig class but still 'No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' is encountered. `public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
            config.EnableCors(cors);
        }`

Comment: Finally, I was able to make it work. It seems my implementation of WebApiConfig class was not being called by my aspnet program. So I added Global.asax and called WebApiConfig from it. In Global.asax, `public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {

        protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        }       
    }`.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but another thing you can check is that you web.config is calling the owin startup with these 2 app settings:

```
<add key="owin:AutomaticAppStartup" value="true" />
<add key="owin:AppStartup" value="MyCompany.MyProduct.MyProject.Startup, MyCompany.MyProduct.MyProject" />
```